# How to get store id by using base url in magento

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I have a base url and I want to get `storeId` from `baseUrl` .
How can I get this?

My code:

```
$baseUrl ="http://marketplace.computenext.com";

$storeId = "";
```

I need to store the ID in the `$storeId` variable.

Comment: <a href="somelinl.com?storeId=<?php echo $test?>">Click here</a>  Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
// Gets the current store's details
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();

// Gets the current store's id
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can receive the first store (id) with the required url:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app("admin");

$stores = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()->getItems();
$baseUrl = 'http://your.url.here.com/';
$searchableStoreId = null;
foreach ($stores as $storeId => $store) {
    $currentStoreUnsecureUrl = Mage::getStoreConfig('web/unsecure/base_url', $storeId);
    $currentStoreSecureUrl = Mage::getStoreConfig('web/secure/base_url', $storeId);
    if ($currentStoreUnsecureUrl == $baseUrl || $currentStoreSecureUrl == $baseUrl) {
        $searchableStoreId = $storeId;
        continue;
    }
}

echo $searchableStoreId; // int store id here or NULL
```